# jconfirm does not work on gridview delete functionality

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a widget that displays information with ObjectDataSource
I have a delete button with a delete command that sends the command directly to ObjectDataSource
I want to show a confirmation before deleting, clicking the confirm button will not do the deletion operation
Please help set up the postback

```
                <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>
                   
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandName="delete" OnClientClick="return confirms(this.name,'Do you want to delete the record?');"><img src="/icons/trash.png" title="Delete" /></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

my script:

```
function confirms(uniqueID,message)
{
    var r = false;
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Alert',
        content: message,
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {

                      __doPostBack(uniqueID, '');
                    
            },
            cancel: function () {
               
              
            }
        }
    });
   
    return r;
}
```

Only the page is refreshed and the record is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

Like most if not all jQuery functions, they are NON BLOCKING. The code does NOT wait.

So, you have to wire up the call to the button AFTER you confirm.

this means:

```
OnClientClick="return confirms(this.name,'Do you want to delete the record?');"
```

Has to always return false. Eg:

```
OnClientClick="confirms(this.name,'Do you want to delete the record?');return false;"
```

the "confirms" routine WILL NOT WAIT and NOT block the js code.

Few exceptions exist when using js - say alert(), and confirm().

Start down the road of jQuery, or plug-ins, they are async code these days.

You can use the built in JavaScript "confirm" and that will work.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm(this.name,'Do you want to delete the record?');"
```

The above works, because the code halts. But jQuery code does not pause or lock up the browser - and for the most part, blocking code is VERY fast being removed from all browser code.

On the other hand, what jConfirm are you using? There is about 500 different ones - some perhaps MIGHT block the code, and perhaps you can have the function return true or false - but then again, we can only guess, right?

I don't see (or know) what "confirm" widget you are using. So, it is a wild guess on my part. And being busy? Don't think I can get back to this post until about 2-3 days from now. And Thanksgiving weekend is coming up. (hint: when you decide to use some js code widget, it would REALLY help if you noted which thinghy you are using).

One approach would be to fire you own post back (and you do seem to be going down that road - I see a postback in your code).

And when you do this, then you have to pick up the postback in the page load event.
(the __DoPostBack will NOT fire the server side (button code behind) events either). However, the post back does occur - and you  can thus pick up what you pass with __DoPostBack in the forms on-load event.

So, you could say do this in your page load:

```
If IsPostBack then

    If Request("__EVENTTARGET") = "Some Button Name ID" Then

       ' the 2nd parm of __DoPostBack can be picked up
       ' with Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")

    End If
End If
```

So, you passing '' for the post back - you might want to say pass some PK ID or some such (say rowindex). However, you will NOT have any events of the grid view fire (such as row command, or index row changed event). So, you quite much have to pass some PK id or other means to figure out what row you are working on. And then call  your routine from above to do whatever you need or want.

You can pass the current PK value with say this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "myclick(this.name," + Eval("ID").ToString + "," +
   Container.DataItemIndex.ToString + ");return false;" %>' />
```

In above, I pass all 3 values.

```
The control name, 
a Eval("row from data source") (you can pick up any data column),
and also the grid index row value.
```

Thus the script for this would be:

```
function myclick(mycontrolname,MyPKID, MyRowIndex) {
            alert('control name = '  + mycontrolname);
            alert('My PK ID = ' + MyPKID);
            alert('My grid row index = ' + MyRowIndex);
        }
```

so, you can pick which of the 3 values you want to pass in your _DoPostBack command, but you have to catch that _DoPostBack in the forms page load event.

So, in theory, you can pass one of the above 3 values (or all of them). Then you pass back one of the above in your _DoPostBack and pick it up in the forms on-load event as per above.